# How to add an existing VC6 project in to a workspace from add-in or VBS macro

Tags: mfc, visual-c++, add-in

I want to add an existing VC6 project in to a workspace from add-in or VBS macro.
There is no function to insert an existing project in Developer Studio's Application object.
So I tried to add a new project (with the same name of existing project) using Application's AddProject method and then overwrite the project file created with my existing project file. But it did not work.
Is there any other way to achive this. Please help.